# Possible ways of representing data in memory (.net)

Tags: .net, data-structures

What are the possible ways of representing data in memory in .Net (or in general)?
It would be great if data could be sorted and looked up by key (or multiple keys).
We are thinking to use collections, arrays, list of collections/arrays.  One object would be in several collections (one sorted asc, other desc, etc.).

Maybe this is not a good idea, and we would like to hear some other possible solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an extremely broad question. See: [data structures](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=data+structures)

The .NET library includes [classes which represent many commonly used data structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f.aspx).

Comment: Hi Mud, very helpful links. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> What are the possible ways of representing data in memory in .Net (or in general)?

In .NET you have two types: [value types and reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) which could be stored differently in memory. Also it's the responsibility of the CLR to decide how to represent data in memory so that the developer shouldn't worry about it.

> It would be great if data could be sorted and looked up by key (or multiple keys)

You may take a look at the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class. You also have [static arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), [dynamic lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), ... (this list is enormous)

Comment: Hi Darin, what structure do you use most of the time? Dictionary or something else? Thanks

Comment: @This is it, the answer depends on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Lets say Bookkeepeing app needs to store a lot of your transactions in RAM, they need to be accessible by date range, type, status, client number etc. Depending on your wish you may want to filter them on any of those parameters. Which data structure should bookkeping app use? Thanks.

Comment: @This is it, you need to define `*a lot of*` (is it 5K, 5M, 5B, more, ...) as well as the characteristics of the server/client computer your application is expected to run on. Is it a server or client application? Are you going to store the transactions of a single client or multiple clients? Are those transactions expected to be accessed in parallel by multiple threads? There are a hell lot of a questions that need to be considered before choosing an appropriate architecture and data types for a specific scenario.

Comment: OK, I thought you can give us few tips but looks like I've vasted your time. Sorry and thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As Mud says, this is a pretty general question so you may need to be a bit more specific for a precise answer for what you want.

In general .NET provides all the 'normal' collection types (Dictionary, List, etc.) like all other good languages.  In addition, .NET provides LINQ which is brilliant for sorting and querying collections.  e.g.

```
var array = new string[] {"banana", "pineapple", "apple", "cherry"};

// basic sorting
var sortedArray = array.OrderBy(a => a).;

foreach (var s in sortedArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// filtering
var filteredArray = array.Where(a => a.Contains("apple"));

foreach (var f in filteredArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

LINQ will work on any sort of collection.  To use it you'll need .NET 3.5 or later and you must add `using System.Linq` to access the necessary extension methods.

Comment: Hi Tim, what is your experience regarding the performance of LINQ? Is it usable in applications where performance is not critical, but it is very important? Thank you

Comment: Performance is generally excellent, provided your queries are well constructed.  In fact, in many cases performance is *better* than with 'traditional' code because the query is built up but not actually executed until you need the results.  This can reduce the number of DB network roundtrips, or reduce the data that has to be processed.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx.  I'd also recommend LinqPad for learning Linq and the test here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqquiz.aspx